# Different behaviors of placeholder attr

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, placeholder

I'm experimenting with placeholder attribute, but I have noticed that if I focus the field on Chrome the placeholder disappears, in Firefox it disappears only after the first keydown.

I like Firefox behaviour: how can I force Chrome to act the same way?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why? Users of the different browsers are used to placeholders behaving in that way for their browser. What's wrong with being consistent?

Comment: @Quentin I want to autofocus the username field on load to make login process quicker, but if I try it in Chrome, the user will never see the placeholder tip, because as soon as the field get focused (on load) the caption disappears. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not to worry about it. It's a tip, if the information was vital it would be in a label.

Comment: @Quentin uhm, it's a login form. What do you suggest between these 2 options?
1) Remove autofocus and be sure that "Username" tip will be seen
2) Keep autofocus and don't mind of users who don't see "Username" tip.

Comment: "username" is not a "tip", it's vital information about what the field does. The [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-placeholder-attribute) makes it clear that you should not use it as a substitute for a label element.

Comment: @Quentin what about Google Sign in? https://accounts.google.com/AddSession?sacu=1

Comment: Username is absolutely not a placeholder tip, this should be a label strongly associated with the form control. In the case you cite Google have a label as well, it has just been hidden - which I would argue is still bad practice.

Comment: @Surferonthefall — Google gave up on writing quality or accessible webpages a long time ago.

Comment: @Surferonthefall Please can you provide a JS Fiddle that concisely replicates the issue, as in Chrome the placeholder is **not** disappearing for me until I begin to enter text.

Comment: (Ironically JS Fiddle's login form is a very good example of how **not** to do this)

Comment: The fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rJ5xJ/ seems to show that Chrome does *not* hide the placeholder value on focus on either Chrome Canary or current.

Comment: @pwdst I have Chrome 14 and your fiddle replicates the issue. If its behavior is now different, the problem is solved.

Comment: Chrome 14?! The current version is 31! I thought the autoupdater was built in long before then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [specification](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-placeholder-attribute) states (emphasis mine)-

> User agents should present this hint to the user, after having
>   stripped line breaks from it, when the element's **value is the empty
>   string** or **the control is not focused** (or **both**), e.g. by displaying it
>   inside a blank unfocused control and hiding it otherwise.

This means that browsers may implement either approach you described above. To deviate from the browser default behaviour you would probably have to write a custom JavaScript solution which would have an on keyup event handler and compare the input value with an empty string.

I would personally implement this using a data-placeholder attribute on the input to hold the value.

As it happens though, it would appear that Chrome has changed its default behaviour as with Chrome Canary and Chrome 31 (which is current), the placeholder value remained visible until the user started typing in the JS Fiddle I linked.

This behaviour was only tested on the "desktop" version of the browser, and only on the Windows operating system. It is possible there may be some variation on other platforms, even with the same browser.

Chrome auto-updates, it is in fact relatively hard to prevent this from happening, so it is highly unlikely that many of your users will be using a version as old as Chrome 14 (released September 2011). Generally it is my experience that statistics will show Chrome versions in use being divided between the last three versions, usually mostly the current and previous version (with ratio dependent on the time since the last release).

As a result, it would appear your issue is unlikely to affect many (if any) users.

Please note the following from the [specification](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-placeholder-attribute) though-

> **Note:** Use of the placeholder attribute as a replacement for a label
>   can reduce the accessibility and usability of the control for a range
>   of users including older users and users with cognitive, mobility,
>   fine motor skill or vision impairments. While the hint given by the
>   control's label is shown at all times, the short hint given in the
>   placeholder attribute is only shown before the user enters a value.
>   Furthermore, placeholder text may be mistaken for a pre-filled value,
>   and as commonly implemented the default color of the placeholder text
>   provides insufficient contrast and the lack of a separate visible
>   label reduces the size of the hit region available for setting focus
>   on the control.

Please don't use the placeholder as a replacement for labels, or at the very least have a hidden label for accessibility purposes (as in the Google example you cited).